# Check user is greater than 18 years from todays date with date picker android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, calendar, android-datepicker

I am trying to check that my user should be 18 years old. If Not then show a toast. (Trying to get from exact today date). But result is getting success only year wise.

Output - Years are getting calculated.
Expected  -  From today's date, user should be 18 years old.

this is what i have tried.

```
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US)
            val dob = sdf.format(calendar.time)

            val userAge = GregorianCalendar(year, month, day)
            val minAdultAge = GregorianCalendar()
            minAdultAge.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18)
            minAdultAge.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1)
            if (minAdultAge.before(userAge)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.txt_18_years_age_validation), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                etDob!!.setText(dob)
            }
        }, year, month, day
    )

    dpd.datePicker.maxDate = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis
    dpd.show()
```

What modifications needed to get validations for todays date.

Thank You.

Comment: seeing as you tested it, you should be able to tell us what still needs fixing. But to me, it seems like you are making it way to hard. get the current date, subtract 18 years, and compare the result of that to the dob. That is all you need.

Comment: Why are you adding Month, -1 ?

Comment: The classes `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `GregorianCalendar` are poorly designed and long outdated. Consider adding ThreeTenABP to your project (search for it) so that you can use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Comment: Your code would seem at first glance to work. Why are you asking a question? Please explain exactly which inadequate bahaviour you are observing. I fon't understand what you mean by *success only yearwise*.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning minAdultAge and the DOB into millis for comparing

```
minAdultAge.timeInMillis > dob.timeInMillis
```

Answer (score 0):

I've edited to show how you could validate the exact age based on the day.
It's meant as a help not a solution.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Calendar present = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar personBirthDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    personBirthDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2001);
    personBirthDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, personBirthDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - 1); // yesterday
    int yearDiff = present.get(Calendar.YEAR) - personBirthDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int dayDiff =  present.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - personBirthDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    System.out.println("Day of person birth year " + personBirthDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    System.out.println("Day of current year " + present.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    System.out.println("Years between " + yearDiff);

    if(present.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - personBirthDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) > 0){
        System.out.println("You are only " + (yearDiff - 1) + " years old");
    }else if(present.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - personBirthDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) < 0) {
        System.out.println("You are already " + yearDiff + " years old");
    }else{
        System.out.println("You are exactly " + yearDiff + " years old");
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, Calendar, really? but, most importantly, this shows a difference in years, that's not the same as age. Every person has two ages in one single year (before and after his birthday). Your solution doesn't take any of this into account.

Comment: I'm using Calendar because that's whats in the question. Sorry if it rubs  you the wrong way ;-)